# Objective-C spaces in strings

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have an object called `exampleObject` with two string properties: `moduleName`, and `pool`.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *moduleName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *pool;
```

Both of these are set using two text fields named  `moduleNameField` and `poolField` respectively, when an IBAction is triggered:

```
if (![[moduleNameField text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [[[appDelegate moduleList] objectAtIndex:[appDelegate moduleNum]] setModulename:[moduleNameField text]];
}
if (![[poolField text] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [[[appDelegate moduleList] objectAtIndex:[appDelegate moduleNum]] setPool:[poolField text]];
}
```

After checking their value with an NSLog statement:

```
NSLog(@"The moduleName is:%@", [[[appDelegate moduleList] objectAtIndex:[appDelegate moduleNum]] moduleName]);
NSLog(@"The pool is:%@", [[[appDelegate moduleList] objectAtIndex:[appDelegate moduleNum]] pool]);
```

I get the correct output:

```
The moduleName is:Module Name One
The pool is:Pool One
```

Here's where it gets weird. Upon calling a function of the `exampleObject`, I try to retrieve the `pool` and `moduleName` properties using:

```
NSString *theModName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [self moduleName]];
NSLog(@"The Name is:%@",theModName);

NSString *thePool = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n", [self pool]];
NSLog(@"The Pool is:%@",thePool);
```

I'm able to get to the first log statement, where it prints:

```
The Name is:Module Name One
```

However, the app crashes on the nextline without an error message. What's even more interesting is that it only crashes when `thePool` is a string with spaces or mixed case. If rather than "Pool One", I had made it "poolone", it would not crash.

Any insight into this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a memory issue and your `NSString*` properties are set to assign. I recommend setting them to `copy` or at least `retain` and making sure you release them in the dealloc method. Since they are set to assign messaging either one could generate a crash at anytime, it just so happens to be `pool` in this case.

Comment: holy hell, that fixed it. I'll be more careful when declaring properties! Thanks :) I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Cocoa memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1), methods like `-text` return an instance you don't own.

If you want to keep them around you need to take ownership, preferrably using a [`copy`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW32) property (to also avoid issues when a mutable string is passed) instead of `assign`:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *moduleName;
```